# Maven-like structure in Dart seems impossible

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I created a little sample on GitHub to test the integration of Dart into a Maven-like structure:

https://github.com/MikeMitterer/dart-WebUIDifferentViews

What I did:

- I turned off the build-script because I could not find an option for the out-Folder.
  So I generated the `src/main/webapp` folder on the command line:

  ```
  dart --package-root=packages/ packages/web_ui/dwc.dart --out \
    src/main/webapp/src/main/dart/app.html
  ```
- OK - works so far, but I had to create the `packages` folder in `webapp` by hand. (`ln -s ../../../packages`).
- Some `href` links are wrong in `app.html`. For example,

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dart/assets/app.css">
  ```

  should point to `../assets/app.css`.
- Next I tried to debug the whole thing.

It failed because the debugger was not able to find the right source directory.

Any solutions?

Comment: I would strongly advise against trying to use Maven structure for a Dart app. As you can see, the tools are not designed to easily accommodate this. More importantly, even if you figure out the tooling problem, other people looking at your code will be confused because you are not following Dart conventions. Use http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html instead.

Comment: The problem is that Dart does not live in its own universe. There are so many WebApps out there following the Maven convention and it should be easy to integrate Dart in such a structure. I like Dart but but on this point I am really disappointed. Anyway - thanks for your comment.

Comment: Although it might not solve the debugger issue, the `pub deploy` command might help with the various relative URLs.  See this post: https://plus.google.com/+SethLadd/posts/VQEJskKoq4h

Comment: Yeah, maybe pub deploy goes in the direction I want. I think I have to play with the deploy-configuration... thx!

Answer (score 2):

There's a Maven plugin for Dart.  Since you last tried using Maven with Dart, more  flexibility was added to pub, for instance the ability to specify the output directory.  This change enabled the Mavin plugin to work better with Dart.

Below is a link to the plugin's page. The plugin is in the Maven central repository, which makes it convenient to use.

https://github.com/dart-maven-plugin/dart-maven-plugin

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.dzwicker.dart/dart-maven-plugin

If you want to use Maven to build/deploy Dart, you should!  It will increase your knowledge of both.  Maven is a valid approach because it's an industrial strength build system that works with all popular version control systems.  Plus it has plugins for deploying your Dart app to remote servers.

As for helping you debug, that seems to involve your IDE.  Dart pub does has build "transformers", which can be used to fix problem link paths in your files.  I've seen reports that debugging Dart from within Intellij is possible.

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html

Dart is a fun language with great promise.  But it is new and doesn't have a rich development tool ecosystem yet.  I use pub to convert Dart code to JavaScript and manage dependencies, but not for deploying the built app.  At of now (Dart 1.5.8), any non-hobby use of Dart probably requires a mature build tool such as Maven, Gradle, or Ant etc.